# Find all the groups a user is member of, including enfolded groups in powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I want to find all the groups a user is member of. Then if those groups are members of other groups etc. Finally i want to end up with a list of IDs with all the groups a user is member of, as well as the groups that have as a member a group that the user may be part of. I dont know how many groups there may be. Does anyone know how to end up with that list of ID in powershell?

Thank you in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkOb8.png)
I have done this so far but i can't do the enumerasion of the groups.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Get-adprincipalgroupmembership?

```
   import-module ActiveDirectory
   Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -identity johndoe | select name, samaccountname
```

Regards
Gab